# Objective-C: animating height constraint change not working

Tags: ios, animation, constraints, autolayout

I have two blocks of code, one working and the second not really. The first adds a view, constraints its height to 0 and then cancel this constraint in an animation block so it grows up. Works perfect. The second one is supposed to reactivate the `0 height constraint` so that its height shrinks back to 0 and then remove it, but instead it is removed instantaneously. Here's the code:

```
self.pickupAddressViewModel.infoViewBlock = ^(MandatoryPickupView * _Nonnull pickupView) {
        if (weakSelf.mandatoryPickupView) {
            return;
        }
        weakSelf.mandatoryPickupView = pickupView;
        [weakSelf.view addSubview:pickupView];

        CGFloat gap = weakSelf.orderButton.originY;
        [[pickupView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:weakSelf.view.bottomAnchor constant:-gap] setActive:YES];
        [[pickupView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:weakSelf.view.leadingAnchor
                                                  constant:16.0] setActive:YES];
        [[pickupView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:weakSelf.view.trailingAnchor
                                                   constant:-16.0] setActive:YES];
        weakSelf.mandatoryPickupViewHeight = [pickupView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:0];
        [weakSelf.mandatoryPickupViewHeight setActive:YES];

        [weakSelf.view layoutIfNeeded];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            [weakSelf.mandatoryPickupViewHeight setActive:NO];
            [weakSelf.view layoutIfNeeded];
        }];
    };
    self.pickupAddressViewModel.closeViewBlock = ^{
        if (!weakSelf.mandatoryPickupView) {
            return;
        }
        [weakSelf.view layoutIfNeeded];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:10.5
                         animations:^{
                             [weakSelf.mandatoryPickupViewHeight setActive:YES];
                             [weakSelf.view layoutIfNeeded];
                         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             [weakSelf.mandatoryPickupView removeFromSuperview];
                             weakSelf.mandatoryPickupView = nil;
                             weakSelf.mandatoryPickupViewHeight = nil;
                         }];
    };
```

1. It's all happening on the main thread.
2. I tried settings the frame's height to 0 instead, also didn't work
3. `weakSelf.mandatoryPickupViewHeight` is a strong property and it is not nil when I activated the second time.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Is `mandatoryPickupViewHeight` strong property?

Comment: Yes, and it is not nil when activated the second time

Comment: Don't call this `[weakSelf.view layoutIfNeeded];`  u can adjust size like `weakSelf.mandatoryPickupViewHeight.constant = 0`

Comment: The constant is already set to 0, I'm just trying to reactivate the constant. And you have to call layoutIfNeeded

Comment: `layoutIfNeeded` is required to make the constraint change work, try change the constant to 0 outside of the animation block, dont need disable it

Comment: The constant is already 0, I'm just reactivating the constraint

Comment: don't active / inactive ,,,, to hide `weakSelf.mandatoryPickupViewHeight.constant = 0` to show `weakSelf.mandatoryPickupViewHeight.constant = SomeHeight`

Comment: @Yotam did you solve it?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ I did, it was the use of a masking layer to round corner. I'm still trying to figure out why it happened before I answer the question. Thanks for helping though

Answer (score 2):

When you are using autolayout for animations, you do it as follows:

1. Make sure autolayout is done:

   ```
   self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
   ```
2. Then you change the constraints BEFORE the animation block. So for example:

   ```
   someConstraint.constant = 0
   ```
3. Then after changing the constraint, you tell the autolayout that constraints have been changed:

   ```
   self.view.setNeedsLayout()
   ```
4. And then you add an animation block with simply calling `layoutIfNeeded()`:

   ```
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
       self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
   })
   ```

Notice that you don't deactivate the constraint - it has to be active the whole time.

I guess that in your code the problem is here:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        [weakSelf.mandatoryPickupViewHeight setActive:NO];
        [weakSelf.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
```

Try changing it to

```
    [weakSelf.mandatoryPickupViewHeight setActive:NO];
    [weakSelf.view setNeedsLayout];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        [weakSelf.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
```

Although what you are doing seems a bit obscure. If the constraint is deactivated, are you sure the autolayout has enough constraints to calculate the proper height? If so, are you sure that `mandatoryPickupViewHeight` constraint is not in collision with those?

Answer (score 0):

This is the methodology to shrink a view to zero height and to make it grows as height as of it's subviews.

```
 -(void)manageViewCollapse
 {

    if(animationRunning)
   {
      return ;
   }

    animationRunning = YES;

  if(supportShown)
  {

      // Hide the view by setting its height constant to zero
      NSLayoutConstraint*full=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.supportView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];


    [self.supportView addConstraint:full];

    // retrieve the bottom constraint of the view with bottom most item and remove it
    for (NSLayoutConstraint*con in self.supportView.constraints)
    {
        if (con.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeBottom && con.firstItem == self.bottomItemView)
        {

            [self.supportView removeConstraint:con];

            break;
        }


    }

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

            }completion:^(BOOL finished){

            supportShown = NO;
            animationRunning = NO ;



            } ];


}
else
{
    // show the view first by deleting it's zero height

    for (NSLayoutConstraint*con in self.supportView.constraints)
    {
        if (con.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeHeight)
        {

            [self.supportView removeConstraint:con];

            break;
        }


    }

   // hook the bottom of the view again to the bottom most item to make it have the correct height

    NSLayoutConstraint*full1=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.bottomItemView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.supportView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:-15.0];

    full1.priority = UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh;

    [self.supportView addConstraint:full1];


      [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

            }completion:^(BOOL finished){

            supportShown = YES;
            animationRunning = NO;


            } ];





}
}
```

Comment: Weird, it works the first time. The whole point is that I want the height to be calculated by inner constraints

Comment: Also forget about active/inactive method