# sequence of auto layout methods get called in rendering cycle

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I was reading about auto layout rendering pipelines i mean how auto layout work under the hood. There are some methods which get called at different stages of autoLayout rendering like

- `layoutIfNeeded()`
- `layoutSubviews()`
- `updateConstraints()`
- `updateConstraintsIfNeeded()`

but i don't know which method is called when and what is the significance of that method and if i want to use auto layout then in which order i can use that methods and how can i control the autoLayout rendering pipeline

Answer (score 1):

Usually you don't need to care about the autolayout method chain. You just need to create the constraints for the views to define their sizes and positions. You can add/remove, activate/deactivate constraints anytime in lifecycle of the view, but you want to always have a set of satisfiable (non-conflicting), yet complete set of constraints.

Take an example. You can tell the autolayout that button `A` should be 50 points wide, 20 points high, with its left top corner positioned at point (0,0) in the `viewController`'s view. Now, this is non-conflicting, yet complete set of constraints for the button `A`. But lets say you want to expand that button, when the user taps it. So in the tap handler you will add one new constraint saying that the button should be 100 points wide - now you have unsatisfiable constraints - there is a constraint say it should be 50 points wide, and another one saying it shoul be 100 points wide. Therefore, to prevent conflict, before activating the new constraint, you have to deactivate the old one. Incomplete constraints is an opposite case, lets say you deactivate the old width constraint, but never activate the new one. Then autolayout can calculate position (because there are constraints defining it), and height, but not width, which usually ends in undefined behavior (now in case of a `UIButton` that's not true, because it has intrinsic size, which implicitly defines its width and height, but I hope you get the point).

So when you create those constraints is up to you (in my example you were manipulating them when the user tapped the button). Usually you start in initializer in case of a `UIView` subclass or in `loadView` in `UIViewController` subclass and there you can define and activate the default set of constraints. And then you can use handlers to react to user activity. My recommendation is prepare all the constraints in `loadView`, keep them in properties, and activate/deactivate them when necessary.

But there are of course some limitation as when and how not to create new constraints - for a more detailed discussion of those cases I really recommend looking at [Advanced Autolayout Toolbox](https://www.objc.io/issues/3-views/advanced-auto-layout-toolbox/) by objc.io.

**EDIT**

See following example of a simple custom `SongView` that uses autolayout for layout and supports also some dynamic changes in constraints by activating/deactivating them. You can just simply copy paste the whole code into a playground and test it out there, or include it in a project.

Notice there that I don't call any of the autolayout lifecycle methods, except of `setNeedsLayout` and `layoutIfNeeded`. `setNeedsLayout` sets a flag telling the autolayout that constraints have been changed, and `layoutIfNeeded` then tells it to recalculate frames. Normally, that would happen automatically, but to animate the constraints changes we need to tell it explicitly - see the `setExpanded` method in `SongView`. For more detailed explanation of using autolayout in animations, see [my different answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48092336/2912282).

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let songView = SongView()
    let button = UIButton()

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        self.view.addSubview(button)
        self.view.addSubview(songView)
        button.setTitle("Expand/Collapse", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(expandCollapse), for: .touchUpInside)

        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        songView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // button has intrinsic size, no need to define constraints for size, position is enough
            button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -50),
            button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),

            // songView has defined its height (see SongView class), but not width, therefore we need more constraints
            songView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor),
            songView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor),
            songView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor),
            ])
    }

    @objc func expandCollapse() {
        if songView.isExpanded {
            songView.setExpanded(to: false, animated: true)
        } else {
            songView.setExpanded(to: true, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

class SongView: UIView {

    private let numberLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
    private let nameLabel: UILabel = UILabel()

    private var expandedConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []
    private var collapsedConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []

    // this can be triggered by some event
    private(set) var isExpanded: Bool = false

    func setExpanded(to expanded: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        self.isExpanded = expanded
        if animated {
            if expanded {
                // setup expanded state
                NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(collapsedConstraints)
                NSLayoutConstraint.activate(expandedConstraints)
            } else {
                // setup collapsed
                NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(expandedConstraints)
                NSLayoutConstraint.activate(collapsedConstraints)
            }
            self.setNeedsLayout()
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                self.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
        } else {
            // non animated version (no need to explicitly call setNeedsLayout nor layoutIfNeeded)
            if expanded {
                // setup expanded state
                NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(collapsedConstraints)
                NSLayoutConstraint.activate(expandedConstraints)
            } else {
                // setup collapsed
                NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(expandedConstraints)
                NSLayoutConstraint.activate(collapsedConstraints)
            }
        }
    }

    var data: (String, String)? {
        didSet {
            numberLabel.text = data?.0
            nameLabel.text = data?.1
        }
    }

    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)

        setupInitialHierarchy()
        setupInitialAttributes()
        setupInitialLayout()
    }

    fileprivate func setupInitialHierarchy() {
        self.addSubview(numberLabel)
        self.addSubview(nameLabel)
    }

    fileprivate func setupInitialAttributes() {
        numberLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.body).pointSize)
        numberLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
        numberLabel.text = "0"
        numberLabel.textAlignment = .right

        nameLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.body)
        nameLabel.text = "NONE"
        nameLabel.textAlignment = .left

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    }

    fileprivate func setupInitialLayout() {
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        numberLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        nameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // just randomly selected different layouts for collapsed and expanded states
        expandedConstraints = [
            numberLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35),
            self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80),
        ]
        collapsedConstraints = [
            numberLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
        ]

        // activating collapsed as default layout
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(collapsedConstraints)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            numberLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 4),
            numberLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -4),
            numberLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 4),

            nameLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: numberLabel.centerYAnchor),
            nameLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: numberLabel.rightAnchor, constant: 8),
            nameLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: -4)
            ])
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```

Comment: you have given nice explanation above but what if i want to build custom view programmatically then how will i manage the different stages of auto layout

as you said above that auto layout will manage all the things but what if i want to take control over the different stages of autolayout or what if i want to take control over specific stage of auto layout and rest of the things will be managed by auto layout

Comment: @RahulGUsai what do you want to manage? what do you want to achieve? there are very little cases in which you have to deal with the autolayout lifecycle, and you haven't explained why you want to deal with it

Comment: scenarios like when i want to make custom view programmatically or when want to animate my changes in constraints

Comment: @RahulGUsai I have updated the answer with an example of a custom view (`SongView`, don't mind the name) + read carefully added explanation about animating, that will show you that in most common cases you don't really need to deal with methods you mentioned in the question